# Macro to atomic scale software

Tags: chemical-engineering, computer-engineering, software, biomechanics

Is there a software that exists that takes a macro object for example a MacBook casing and its composition (Aluminum) and allow you to zoom between the macro scale (a fully rendered MacBook) and the atomic scale (a view of the atomic structure).

I've played around with VMD, PyMol, ASE, CAD. The first 3 are focused on the molecular level, but CAD is for designing macro scale objects. Can't seem to find a combination of both

Comment: What have you found so far? Or do you expect us to search for you?

Comment: @SolarMike I've updated my question with softwares I've discovered and played around with. The goal was to see if anybody in this community has already discovered this type of software should it exist.